# How to get the URL of a page in Puppeteers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I make a function to create a PDF with Puppeteers :

```
async function createpdf(url) {
        let browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    
        let page = await browser.newPage();
    
        let url = () => { return window.location.href};
    
        await page.goto(url, {
            waitUntil: "networkidle0"
        }) ;
    
        const pdf = await page.pdf({
            printBackground: true,
            format: "Letter",
            margin: {
                top: "20px",
                bottom: "40px",
                left: "20px",
                right: "20px"
            }
        });
    
    
        browser.close();
    
        return pdf;      
    }
```

And in another route I made the PDF request.

```
app.get('/gerarpdf', async(req,res) => {
       
         
        let pdf = await createpdf('**current URL**');

        res.contentType('application/pdf');
        res.send(pdf);
});
```

But the page URL is the result of filling out several forms, I left it in GET so the values ​​go to the URL and are updated all the time.
How can I get this URL and put it inside this function to generate the PDF?

Forms, I left the form in 'get' to be able to access the url by puppeteers :

```
<form name='form1' action="/add" method="get">
                <h2>Tipo de documento: "Procuração Jurídica: Petição Inicial" </h2>

                    <div class = "Parte">
                    <label for = "nVara">Número da Vara:</label>
                    <input type ="text" name ="nVara" id ="nVara" class ="input-padrao"  placeholder="Numero da vara">

                    <label for = "comarca">Comarca:</label>
                    <input type ="number" name ="comarca" id ="comarca" class ="input-padrao"  placeholder="Comarca">

                    <label for = "nomeparte">Nome da parte:</label>
                    <input type ="text" name ="nomeparte" id ="nomeparte" class ="input-padrao"  placeholder="Nome da Parte">

                    <label for = "nacionalidade">Nacionalidade da parte: </label>
                    <input type ="text" name ="nacionalidade" id ="nacionalidade" class ="input-padrao"  placeholder="Nacionalidade">

                    <label for = "estadocivil">Estado Civil da parte: </label>
                    <input type ="text" name ="estadocivil" id ="estadocivil" class ="input-padrao"  placeholder="Estado Civil">

                    <label for = "profissao">Profissão da Parte: </label>
                    <input type ="text" name ="profissao" id ="profissao" class ="input-padrao"  placeholder="Profissão">

                    <label for = "rg">RG: </label>
                    <input type ="text" name ="rg" id ="rg" class ="input-padrao" placeholder="RG">
```

The route:

```
app.get('/add', function(req, res){

    
                let peticao = [{
                    
                        Vara: req.query.nVara,
                        Comarca: req.query.comarca, 
                        NomeParte: req.query.nomeparte,
                        Nacionalidade: req.query.nacionalidade,
                        EstadoCivil: req.query.estadocivil,
                        Profissao: req.query.profissao,
                        Rg: req.query.rg, 
                        OExp: req.query.orgaoexpedidor,
                        Cpf: req.query.cpf,
                        Email: req.query.email, 
                        Endereco: req.query.endereco,
                        EndAdv: req.query.enderecoadvogado, 
                        Acao: req.query.acao, 
                
                        NomeReu: req.query.nomereu,
                        NacReu: req.body.nacionalidadereu, 
                        EstReu: req.query.estadocivilreu,
                        ProReu: req.query.profissaoreu,
                        RgReu: req.query.rgreu, 
                        OExpReu: req.query.orgaoexpedidorreu, 
                        CpfReu: req.query.cpfreu,
                        EmailReu: req.query.emailreu,
                        EndReu: req.query.enderecoreu,
                        Relato: req.query.relato, 
                        Fundamentos: req.query.fundamentos,
                        Provas: req.query.provas, 
                        Valor: req.query.valor,
                        Local: req.query.local,
                        Dia: req.query.dia, 
                        Mes: req.query.mes,
                        Ano: req.query.ano, 
                        Advogado: req.query.advogado, 
                        Oab: req.query.oab, 
                        Uf: req.query.uf
                
                }] 
res.render('pdf', {dados: peticao});//Here the route send the date to 'pdf.handlebars'.
```

Comment: You can extract the url from the `req.body` when sending it via form (in case you have `body-parser` enabled. Can you show the html form in which you do the request?:

Comment: How i can do this?

Comment: So basically you want to fill out a form, then create a pdf out of the filled out form?, resp. out of the same page but with data filled in, Right? I don't qieut understand what you want.